# Ionic modal firstFocus not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic App that that when a modal launches it suppose to focus the first input. which is the input element with an ID of #discount.

this is my view.

```
<script id="discount.html" type="text/ng-template">
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
        <h1 class="title">Add Discount</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">Price</span>
                <input type="tel" autofocus class="button-large button-block text-center input-lg" id="discount" ng-model="payment.discountPrice"  ui-money-mask="2" />
            </label>
            <br>
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">Name</span>
                <input type="text" class="button-large button-block input-lg" ng-model="payment.discountName" />
            </label>
            <br>
            <button class="button button-large button-block button-positive" ng-click="submitDiscount()">Apply</button>
            <button class="button button-large button-block button-assertive" ng-click="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

this is my controller.

```
    $scope.openDiscountModal = function () {

  //cache the modal
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('discount.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up',
    focusFirstInput: true,
    backdropClickToClose: false
  }).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
    $scope.modal.show().then(document.getElementById('discount').focus());
    console.log('xxx');
  });

};
```

this works fine in the desktop browser but it doesn't focus on my IOS ionic app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For iOS, you need to add the following configuration in your **config.xml** file.

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

Please refer the *KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction* section in this [iOS Configuration](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide/platforms/ios/config.html) article.

*Bydefault KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction is set as **true***.

After adding the configuration preference, your code will no longer required this code for focusing your first field

```
then(document.getElementById('discount').focus()
```

You can simply use

```
$scope.modal.show()
```

Because `focusFirstInput: true` will automatically focus the first field, in your case *discount* input field.